# Evaluation of the contour integral $\int_\beta \frac{e^z}{e^z-\pi} \mathrm dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration, residue-calculus

> Suppose $\beta$ is a loop in the annulus $\{z:10<\left|z\right|<12\}$ that winds $N$ times about the origin in the counterclockwise direction, where $N$ is an integer.  Determine the value of the contour integral $$\int_\beta \frac{e^z}{e^z-\pi} \mathrm dz$$

Well, it certainly looks like a Cauchy's theorem problem of some kind, but I'm not sure how to get it in the right format.  Algebraically it doesn't seem like there's any way to turn this into the form $$\int \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^n}\mathrm dz$$ The only idea I have is to somehow consider this in "$e^z$ space," but I'm not sure how to pull this off.

(Note: This is exam review, not homework.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f:z\mapsto \dfrac{e^z}{e^z-\pi}=\dfrac{e^z}{g(z)}$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb C$ and has three poles in the interior of the loop $\beta$.

They are the zeros of $g$, $z_k=\ln(\pi)+2ik\pi$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, that have a modulus lesser than 10, i.e. $z_{-1}=\ln(\pi)-2i\pi$, $z_0=\ln(\pi)$ and $z_1=\ln(\pi)+2i\pi$.

You can easily check that the other zeros of $g$ have a modulus greater than 12.

We have, for all $k\in\Bbb Z$, $\mathrm{Res}(f,z_k)=\displaystyle\lim_{z\to z_k}\ (z-z_k) f(z)=\dfrac{e^{z_k}}{g'(z_k)}=\dfrac{e^{z_k}}{e^{z_k}}=1$

By the residue theorem : $\displaystyle\int_\beta f(z) dz=2i\pi\sum_{k=-1}^1I(\beta,z_k)\mathrm{Res}(f,z_k)=6i\pi N$

Comment: To prove that $e^z-\pi$ has $3$ zeroes in that range, would it be true that it suffices to notice that $e^{z\pm 2\pi i}-\pi=e^z-\pi$, so because $e^z-\pi$ has one real zero for real $z$ it has exactly two zeroes within $|z|<12$?

Comment: I wouldn't say that ! This is what I did : I solved the equation $g(z)=0$ and drew the two circles $\{z\in\Bbb C : |z|=10\}$ and $\{z\in\Bbb C : |z|=12\}$ with a few zeros of $g$ in Geogebra to quickly see if any zeros were in the annulus. Then I proved what I wrote in my answer with a few calculus : I know that $e<3<\pi<4<e^2$, so $\ln(\pi)<\ln(e^2)=2$ and $6<2\pi<8$. So you have : $|z_0|=\ln(\pi)<2<10$, $|z_{-1}|=|z_1|=\sqrt{\ln(\pi)^2+(2\pi)^2}<\sqrt{4+64}<\sqrt{100}=10$ and if $|k|>1$, $|z_k|\geq |\mathrm{Im}(z_k)|=2|k|\pi\geq 4\pi>12$

Answer (score 3):

Lets do this another way:
$$\int_\beta \frac{e^z}{e^z-\pi}\,\mathrm{d}z = \int_\beta \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1-e^{\log(\pi)-z}} = \int_\beta \frac{(z-\log(\pi))(1-e^{\log(\pi)-z})^{-1}}{z-\log(\pi)}\,\mathrm{d}z$$
I claim $f(z) = (z-\log(\pi))(1-e^{\log(\pi)-z})^{-1}$ is analytic near $\log(\pi)$, for
$$f(z) = \frac{z-\log(\pi)}{1-e^{\log(\pi)-z}} = \frac{z-\log(\pi)}{-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}(\log(\pi)-z)^n} = \frac{1}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}(\log(\pi)-z)^{n-1}},$$
and thus especially $f(\log(\pi))=1$.

As Girianshiido remarks, there are three relevant $\log(\pi)$'s.

Hence by Cauchy, $\displaystyle \int_\beta \frac{f(z)}{z-\log(\pi)}\,\mathrm{d}z = 3\cdot 2\pi i N$.

Comment: Can you briefly describe the image of $\beta$ under your change-of-variables transformation?

Comment: Thanks. I second Steven's request. Also, are there any branch cut issues I should be looking out for here?

Comment: Yeah, call me dumb, but I still can't figure out how this changes the winding number.

Comment: I changed the wolfram alpha picture to a Foo plot picture which does the job.

Comment: @Abel do you know how the winding number increase could be proved symbolically?  I made that plot in mathematica also but i don't understand why this happens.

Comment: It would be very messy. I just decided to use a different approach altogether. Do you like this better?

Comment: Let me see... I'll try to understand it

Comment: @Abel What happens to the "$1-$" in the denominator in the $2^\text{nd}$ equality in the $2^\text{nd}$ inline equation?

Comment: It is cancelled by the $n=0$ term in the sum.

Comment: @Abel ah right, ok, yeah.  reading.

Comment: Girianshiido's answer just made me realise that there are actually three poles instead of 1. Branch cuts indeed. This is of course also consistent with the threefold increase in the winding number the Foo plot showed. I suggest you accept his/her answer.

Comment: @Abel alright but i'm upvoting yours still :)